# How to prove $\log\left(\frac e{2t}\right) \approx \log\left(\frac1t\right)$ for $0 < t < \frac 12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> How do you prove $\log\left(\dfrac e{2t}\right) \approx \log\left(\dfrac1t\right)$ for $0 < t < \dfrac 12$?

I've simplified this to proving just $\log(2) \approx 1$. How do I prove this now without using a calculator?

Comment: What do you mean by $\approx$? Also, can you use power series? the value of $e$? And...? (Btw, $\log=\ln$ right?)

Comment: To have some precise numbers, $0.69 < \log 2 < 0.70$, so this is a terrible approximation.

Comment: @idk I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In fact you have $$\log\left(\dfrac e{2t}\right)-\log\left(\dfrac 1t\right)=\log\left(\dfrac e2 \right)=1-\log2$$ You assume that $1-\log2\approx0\implies e\approx 2$ which is not a very good approximation.